# Kafka log directories in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

When i was running the kafka and zookeeper without Docker, I could see the topic partitions log files in the /tmp/kafka-logs directory. Now with Docker, even though i specify the log directory in the Volumes section in docker-compose.yml, i cant see the files in the docker VM, like "TOPICNAME-PARTITIONNUMBER".. Is there anything I'm missing here ? Any idea on where i could find these directories in Docker VMs..

```
zookeeper:
 image: confluent/zookeeper
 container_name: zookeeper
 ports:
   - "2181:2181"
   - "15001:15000"
 environment:
 ZK_SERVER_ID: 1
 volumes:
   - /tmp/docker/zk1/logs:/logs
   - /tmp/docker/zk1/data:/data

 kafka1:
  image: confluent/kafka
  container_name: kafka1
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    - "15002:15000"
  links:
    - zookeeper
  environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_STORAGE: kafka
    # This is Container IP
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100 

  volumes:
    - /tmp/docker/kafka1/logs:/logs
    - /tmp/docker/kafka1/data:/data
```

Comment: Are you sure your containerized Kafka is keeping logs in `/logs`?

Comment: I can just see the folder structures created as per the docker-compose files and i dont see any data present in those log files/

Comment: Have you tried entering the container and checking what's inside `\logs` dir? I.e. `docker exec -it kafka1 bash` and `ll /logs`?

Comment: Yes thanks it worked..

Answer (score 5):

this is how we configured for logs in our compose file and it has the log files in it. You should jump onto the container to see the '/var/lib/kafka/data', directory and the data inside it

> volumes:
>
> -kb1_data:/var/lib/kafka/data

Comment: This answer is correct, the var/lib/kafka/data/<topicname> folder is the default location for the log files in a docker container based on the confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0 image.

Comment: You can also find the reference on Confluence's page here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/external-volumes.html#data-volumes-for-kafka-and-zk

Answer (score 0):

Remember that 1st parameter in list for volumes, ports and other fields about sharing resources in docker-compose is about host, the 2nd is about the container.
So you should change the order for your volumes values.

```
zookeeper:
 image: confluent/zookeeper
 container_name: zookeeper
 ports:
   - "2181:2181"
   - "15001:15000"
 environment:
 ZK_SERVER_ID: 1
 volumes:
   #- ./host/folder:/container/folder
   - ./logs:/tmp/docker/zk1/logs
   - ./data:/tmp/docker/zk1/data
    
kafka1:
  image: confluent/kafka
  container_name: kafka1
  ports:
    #- "host-port:container-port"
    - "9092:9092"
    - "15002:15000"
  links:
    - zookeeper
  environment:
    - KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    - KAFKA_OFFSETS_STORAGE: kafka
    - # This is Container IP
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100 
  volumes:
    #- ./host/folder:/container/folder
    - ./logs:/tmp/docker/kafka1/logs
    - ./data:/tmp/docker/kafka1/data
```

Comment: The `confluent/` docker images are not maintained. Should be `confluentinc/`. Also, the containers don't store data under `/tmp/docker`